# Passing mongodb ISODate in R

Tags: r, rmongo

I'm currently pulling my data into R with the RMongo package. I want to specify the date range that should be pulled in my R session at this point with

```
library('RMongo')

#Connect to the database
mongo <- mongoDbConnect('db')

#results from dates. 
result <- dbGetQuery(mongo, 'statsdb', '<query>', 0,200000)

Where my <query> is 
 { "createdAt" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2012-12-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2013-01-01T00:00:00Z")  } }
```

I'm getting errors:

`Error in .jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "S", "dbGetQuery", collection,  : com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:`

Is there a specific way i need to pass mongodb ISODates in R with the RMongo package?

Answer (score 6):

I just spent considerable time struggling with this myself. If you're still looking for an answer, the key seems to be in MongoDB extended JSON; see

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

For your query, you could write

```
query = "{ createdAt : { $gte : { $date: '2012-12-01T00:00:00Z' }, 
                         $lt : { $date: '2013-01-01T00:00:00Z' } } }"
```